# "incorrect syntax near keyword 'WHERE' " Exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Userinformation(Access)
          VALUES("+nameAccess.Text+") WHERE User_ID='"+userIdaccess.Text+"'",con);
  SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
  if (dr.Read())
  {
    MessageBox.Show("User Access Blocked");
  }
  dr.Close();
```

It is giving an exeption as below:

> "incorrect syntax near keyword 'WHERE' "

Answer (score 5):

Use parametrized queries to avoid SQL injection and also ensure to properly encode the query and also wrap your `IDisposable` resources in [using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to avoid leaking unmanaged handles. Also an INSERT SQL statement doesn't have a `WHERE` clause:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Userinformation(Access) VALUES(@NameAccess)", con))
{
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameAccess", nameAccess.Text);

    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User Access Blocked");
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime you use the `+` operator when building a SQL query you are **doing it wrong**.

Comment: INSERT INTO doesn't have a WHERE clause.

Comment: @FedorHajdu, oops you are right. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `INSERT .. VALUES... WHERE`, that's why. It's invalid syntax.

Insert Syntax : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO doesn't have a WHERE clause. You can either do an UPDATE... WHERE your clause is met or insert both user info and user id as a new row.

Answer (score -1):

try this code :

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Userinformation(Access)
                                   VALUES('"+nameAccess.Text+"')",con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
   MessageBox.Show("User Access Blocked");
}
dr.Close();
```

Insert query have no `where clause`

Comment: Can you spell [SQL injection attacks?!?!?](http://xkcd.com/327/) - you should **never** concatenate together a SQL statement - [use **parametrized queries** instead](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) - **always!**